# A six letter Name

Tags: word, knowledge

Can you figure this out?

> It's a name
>
> And a Surname
>
> An island
>
> A code
>
> Three US states
>
> And also elements

A six letter word that ends in a college, that will need some knowledge.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This six letter word that ends in a college may be

> **Pascal**, with Cal being UC Berkeley.

It's a name, And a Surname

> Pascal is a first name meaning one born on Easter, and Blaise Pascal.

An island

> There are islands named Pascal in Antarctica and off Western Australia.

A code

> Pascal is a programming language developed by Niklaus Wirth in 1970.

Three US states

> Pennsylvania - PA, South Carolina - SC, Alabama - AL

And also elements

> Protactinium - Pa, Scandium - Sc, Aluminium - Al